# How does Spring-data handle/retrieve data populated by triggers and not by itself?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a problem with *Spring Data + MySQL triggers*.

Currently, before a new row is inserted in a table, a MySQL trigger assigns data to specific columns:

**Table** `User`

**Columns** `created_at` and `updated_at`

Those columns are mapped as follow:

```
@Column(name = "created_at")
private Date createdAt;

@Column(name = "updated_at")
private Date updatedAt;
```

Likewise, I have a service (`annotated as @Transactional`) which populates with data the instance `User` but `created_at` and `updated_at`, I mean, when I'm calling `save` for the `userRepository` those attributes go as `nulls`.

MySQL before to insert ***(trigger)*** into DB, both attributes are populated with the MySQL function `utc_timestamp()`.

**My problem:**

Just after I call the service `saveUSer`, I'm calling `findById` from the repository. *Why both attributes `created_at` and `updated_at` has null value in the instance (in db they have values)?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After saving an user , the instance will be cached inside the `EntityManager`. If the call of `findById` is still in the same transaction that is used to save the user , it will just return that user instance that is cached inside the `EntityManager` which the `createdAt` and `updatedAt` are null.

In JPA , we can call `entityManager.refresh(user)` to force selecting that user from the DB such that the user instance managed by JPA will have the latest values as the DB record. So you can use `entityManager.refresh(user)` after saving the user to ensure the latest value of `createdAt` and `updatedAt` are updated back to the user instance managed by JPA.

However , Spring data 's JPA repository does not expose EntityManager 's `refresh`, you can extend it like [this](https://dzone.com/articles/adding-entitymanagerrefresh-to-all-spring-data-rep).

Answer (score 1):

The other answer quite accurate, however it assumes you call `saveUser` and `findById` from inside an a transaction.
However when you use Spring Data JPA under Spring Boot this issue could happen even if you are out of a transaction.

Spring Boot has a default setting which automatically encapsulates each request in a transaction.
So, if you use Spring Boot it would worth a try to add the following line to the application.properties:
`spring.jpa.open-in-view=false`